# Failed to sign in. Google Play Games Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-games

I wanted to update an app I already published in the playstore to add achievements and leaderboard.

I have created the game in the Developer Console and everything was fine, everything worked with the debug SHA1 I have entered in the Google API for my app.

But now I have generated a signed APK with a different SHA1 (of course), and I have changed the debug SHA1 in Google API with the SHA1 for my signed APK.

I have pushed the APK to the playstore and published the game from the Developer Console. But now that my game is available in the store, when people try to connect to the Google Play Games they get "Failed to Sign in. Please check you network connection and try again".

I already looked at [this link](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#top_of_page)
but I am doing everything correctly.

Is it possible that I need to wait several hours before Google API handle the new SHA1 I have entered ? I have no idea of what is going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so for everyone having the same problem as me.

Don't forget that now Google can sign your app.

The SHA1 fingerprint i needed was in the developer console, no need to get the SHA1 fingerprint of my APK.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26819268/5832311). Try to move the `app ID` and `leaderboard ID` from `strings.xml` to `ids.xml` in values folder. You may also try to delete all client ids then add them again for debug keystore and release keystore.

Here's an additional reference which might also help: [LIBGDX game configuration with google Play game services Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914366/libgdx-game-configuration-with-google-play-game-services-errors)

> Here are a few points that might help you.
>
> - It takes several hours before your changes on Developer Console are actually published. Test the game after a few hours.
> - You don't need to publish in order to test it. You can do that by adding tester accounts in your developer console.
> - You can't "test" Google Play Services with developer account. You will need another account for that.
>
> Edit:
>   **Very Important:**
>
> Make sure you added required permissions to AndroidManifest.xml in
>   your Android project.